# How to autoindent code in multiple files with eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, indentation, auto-indent

It is simple to autoindent the code in one source file in eclipse CDT (Ctrl-I will indent the selection).

Is there a way to do it on multiple files at once? I need to auto-indent all the source files in my C++ project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Multi-select the files (or directories) of ugly code.
2. Invoke the Source/Format menu command,

Comment: Indeed that will "Format" the code, but that does much more than indenting it. The "Indent" option in the menu is grayed out when multi-selecting. Perhaps I could go into Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Code Style -> Formatter and see if it possible to configure it to indent only.